# Discord.py auxiliary function not executing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I have a running discord bot using Python, however, I am doing a rewrite to condense the code for other contributors to contribute code by adding an additional function that should reduce the reuse of code.

However, in the code, the function textCom is not able to recognize client.send_message

I have tried adding async to the def of the textCom function, however, this results in no response by the bot.

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'token'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # commands cannot be executed in private messages
    if message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private:
        return


    # original code
    if message.content.startswith('!text1'):
        msg = "text1 executed".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)  

    # new code I want executed
    def textCom(textMessage):
        msg = textMessage.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    if message.content.startswith('!text2'):
        textCom("text2 executed")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The python script run, however, when a user types !text1 the bot replies with "text1 executed" but when a user types !text2 the bot does not reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpreter should be raising a syntax error when you define `on_message`, before the bot even starts.  You can't have an `await` inside a non-async function.

Make `textCom` an `async def` function and `await` it when you call it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    async def textCom(textMessage):
        msg = textMessage.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    if message.content.startswith('!text2'):
        await textCom("text2 executed")
```